# how to plot swarmplot/stripplot with style-coded and color-coded at same time

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data that I want to plot them as style-coded and color-coded at same time. but they are overlapping with each other, so I need to have the dots swarmed or jittered.

seaborn have the option for doing style-coded and color-coded at same time in scatter.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", style="time")
```

[image]

yet in the swarmplot/stripplot,  only hue is allowed, but not style-coded

(btw, I know that seaborn scatter plot have "jitter" argument, but as 11/1/2020, it's not working yet)

I wonder if there is a method to make the data swarmed or jittered while style-coded and color-coded

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the scatterplot, some jitter can be added:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", style="time")
for dots in ax.collections:
    offsets = dots.get_offsets()
    jittered_offsets = offsets + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, offsets.shape)
    dots.set_offsets(jittered_offsets)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]